# How do I use jQuery .each on a javascript var defined as a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, each, var

I'm trying to loop through the table rows of a tbody:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const maxPageHeight=600;
    console.log(`document ready`)
    let invNum=0;
    $(`.ordDiv`).each(function(){
        invNum++;
        $curOrdDiv=$(this);
        let curInvPage=1;
        let curInvHeight=0;
        let curPageHeight=0;
        curPageHeight=$curOrdDiv.find(`.table1`).height()+$curOrdDiv.find(`.table2`).height();
        const $prodTable=$curOrdDiv.find(`.invoiceTable5 > tbody`)[0];
        console.log($prodTable);
        $prodTable.each(`tr`, function(){ //<---this is the line causing the issues
            curPageHeight+=$(this).height();
            if (curPageHeight>=maxPageHeight){
                $(this).before(`<br/>Invoice :${invNum} Page ${curInvPage} of <span class="invNumPages"></span><P class="breakhere">&nbsp;</p>`);
                curInvPage++;
                curPageHeight=$(this).height();
            }
        })
        $curOrdDiv.find(`.invNumPages`).text(curInvPage);
    });
});
```

I can't loop through $prodTable. I get "TypeError: $prodTable.each is not a function"

Update:
I finally just resorted to this:

```
    const $prodTable=$curOrdDiv.find(`.invoiceTable5`);
    console.log($prodTable);
    $prodTable.find(`tr`).each(function(){
        console.log($(this));
        curPageHeight+=$(this).height();
        if (curPageHeight>=maxPageHeight){
            $(this).before(`<tr class="forceBreak" style="page-break-after:always"><td colspan="6"><span style="float:right; padding-right:10px"> Invoice: ${invNum} Page ${curInvPage} of <span class="invNumPages"></span></span></td></tr>`);
            curInvPage++;
            curPageHeight=$(this).height();
        }
    })
```

Comment: remove that `[0]` from the end, it is selecting the element without jQuery, or use `.eq(0)`

Comment: Bracket notation will return the base element, but you want the jQuery object, not the element. Use `.eq` instead

Comment: Sorry. I was down that road already. I'm back to const $prodTable=$curOrdDiv.find(`.invoiceTable5`);    I get a valid jQuery object, I can see it in the console window with rows.